# Is the information about C# 8 nullable reference types stored in a .NET assembly?

Tags: c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

Will consumers of a Nuget package written in C# 8 with nullable reference types see the information about nullability of fields / parameters defined in that package? Will the C# 8 compiler be able to use that information to issue appropriate warnings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, provided they also use C# 8 or later and have `Nullable` enabled. This already happens with the BCL types.

NRTs in C# 8 don't introduce a new kind of type. The compiler generates  `NullableContext` and `Nullable` attributes in projects or files where NRTs are enabled. These are used to analyze the code and issue nullability warnings. Whether nullability is enabled or not, a `string` and a `string?` are still the same type, a `string`.

Jon Skeet's [NullableAttribute And C# 8](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/02/10/nullableattribute-and-c-8/) explains how those attributes work and how they affect the public API of a package, in this case Noda Time. The package was ported to C# 8 back in February 2019.

As Jon Skeet explains:

> The C# 8 compiler creates an internal NullableAttribute class within the assembly (which I assume it wouldn’t if we were targeting a framework that already includes such an attribute) and applies the attribute anywhere it’s relevant.

This makes the change transparent to older C# compilers

Check [this Sharplab.io example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+BiAdgVwBtCJhC4ACOXU8gWACgABAJgEZGmAGCptgOgBK+XDACWYOPwDCAezAAHMeQQBlRADcxAYzhQA3JwDMvFhWkUA3owq3eJpgBYKAWQAUF7QEorNuwF9GfyA). The following simple class:

```
#nullable enable
using System;
public class C {
    public void M(C c) {
    }
}
```

Generates this intermediate C# code:

```
public class C
{
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(1)]
    public void M(C c)
    {
    }
}
```

While [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+BiAdgVwBtCJhC4ACOXU8gWACgABAJgEZGmAGCptgOgBK+XDACWYOPwDCAezAAHMeQQBlRADcxAYzhQA3JwDMvFhWkUA3owq3eJiwFkAFNID8FbQEorNu/6YAdk8KNw8YAAsEWQB3Clw4OIBBBABzfElRADkiQgBRAA9dBXFZXGcaSVkAM2dvL0MGfwBfRmagA==) :

```
    public C M(C? c) {
        return c ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(c));
    }
```

Generates this intermediate C# :

```
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(1)]
    public C M([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Nullable(2)] C c)
    {
        if (c != null)
        {
            return c;
        }
        throw new ArgumentNullException("c");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've a short question. You mentioned that it if the depending assmbly is compiled using C#8 and enabled NRT it will produce a warning. What if we've an common assembly referenced by multiple assemblies and none of them have NRT enabled. Will it produce any warnings if we introduce NRT to this common assembly? Or do we need to enable NRT for ALL assemblies referencing this one transitively to get warnings?

Comment: There is another question upcoming: What happens at runtime? The current code performs a null check and raises an exception if the parameters doesn't match this condition. This ArgumentNullException raising code will be removed if we enable NRT. I suppose this will result in an NullReferenceException at runtime. Am I right?